# get unique values from query_set Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to get unique results from s query_set.

Example.

```
ID     |    NOMBRE    |    CLASIFICACION
1           Escoba         Limpieza
2           Trapeador      Limpieza
3           Tornillo       Herramienta
```

I want to get "Limpieza and Herramienta" only. currently I'm getting "Limpieza, Limpieza and Herramineta"

my views.py:

```
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model= Items

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['clasificacion'] =Items.objects.order_by('nombre').distinct('clasificacion')
        return context
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Items(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    codigo_proveedor = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    clasificacion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    c_minima = models.IntegerField()
    c_actual = models.IntegerField()
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey('Proveedores',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre + '   -----   ' + 
               self.clasificacion + '   -----    ' + 
               str(self.c_actual)


class Proveedores(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    direccion2 = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    active =  models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
context['clasificacion'] = Items.objects.order_by('clasificacion', 'nombre').distinct('clasificacion')
```

`distinct()` must match the leftmost `order_by()`. So making the column you use in `distinct()` the first column in the `order_by()` makes it work.

Comment: just tryed it out and I'm still getting 3 results ( "Limpieza ,Limpieza and Herramientas" ). Might it be the template it self ?

Comment: Try pasting this under that line and see if just 2 print:
    `for person in context['clasificacion']:
        print(person.clasificacion)`

Comment: I still get 3 results in the webpage and in the terminal  for the " for" statement. Some times i get an error while loading the site.

Comment: the error is: "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend" . but is random. it works if a remove 'clasificacion' out from .distinct()

Comment: sqlite3 doesn't support `distinct`. What database backend are you using? I tested it with PostgreSQL and it works.

Comment: i was using sqlite3.  I've tryed installing postgresql but when i changed the backend on Django it gave me a bunch of errors. i provided the name, host, user, password, and port. i runed the python manage.py migrate and got issues

Comment: I installed postgres locally is there a step i skiped ?

Comment: Are you using the correct engine? `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',`

Comment: yes, this is the error i get:"    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
"

Comment: and this is how i configured the backend :
    `DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'postgres',
            'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
            'USER':'user',
            'PASSWORD':'password.',
            'PORT':'5432', 
        }
    }`

Comment: i whent back to slqite3   and we got it to work this time  we used :
`context['clase'] = Items.objects.all().order_by('clase').values('clase').distinct()` .Thankyou very very much !  Ichanged the models field name it was a bit to long XP

Answer (score 0):

Will's response is correct, but I think you want to do the order_by() operation first to ensure you are getting the correct results.

```
context['clasificacion'] =(Items
                          .objects
                          .order_by('clasification', 'nombre')
                          .distinct('clasificacion'))
```

Comment: I've tryed both  examples and still end up with 3 results instead of 2